# What is wrong with this area? Getting 2 semantic and 1 parse issue

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Using Xcode to write an app using the "Get Current Location" method. Getting a `Parse issue, Expected ';' after method prototype` however when I add it I keep on getting more errors, so im assuming that its just that one. I also am receiving two semantic issues with missing context for method declaration. The parse issue is on line 1 of the section and the semantic issues appear on lines 11 and 20. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
- (IBAction)getCurrentLocation:(id)sender {
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation]; 
}

@end

pragma mark - CLLocationManagerDelegate

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
        didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@", error);
    UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                               initWithTitle:@"Error"
                               message:@"Failed to Get Your Location"
                               delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                               otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [errorAlert show]; 
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
        didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation 
        fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
    CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

    if (currentLocation != nil) {
        longitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f",
                                        currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
        latitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f",
                                       currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    } 
}
```

Comment: Don't use blockquotes for code. Just indent the code four (or more) spaces. I did what I could but it still doesn't look right to me.

Comment: I deleted my answer - please go buy a book -- we aren't a 'static analyser'

Answer (score 0):

xcode is not a smart debugger/compiler so when you get a stupid error it might not be from the place it was :)
In this situation i think you have missed the "#" sign before the "pragma mark"
Thats why Xcode keeps giving errors and warnings :)
hope it helped